# Required Positional Argument,"Type Error: missing self argument"

Tags: python

```
    from tkinter import *
    
    import time
    
    import random


    colorbg = "#1d3557"

    

def MainPage(x,y):

    def yes():
        p = name_entry.get()
        print(x)
        
    
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("1920x1080")
    window.state("zoomed")
    #================================================Variables========================================================
    name_entered = StringVar()
    phone_entered = StringVar()

    Label(window, text="Stock Purchase Page",width=80, font=("Candara",30),fg="white",bg=colorbg,bd=10,relief=GROOVE).pack()
    f1 = LabelFrame(window, text="Customer Details", font=("Candara",15),fg="gold",bg=colorbg,bd=10,relief=GROOVE)
    f1.place(x=0,y=75,relwidth=1)

    name = Label(f1, text="Customer Name",bg=colorbg,fg="white", font=("Candara",18,"bold",)).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20,pady=5)
    name_entry = Entry(f1,bg="white", width=15,textvariable=name_entered, font=("Candara",15),bd=5, relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=0,column=1,pady=5,padx=20)


    phone = Label(f1, text="Customer Phone Number",bg=colorbg,fg="white", font=("Candara",18,"bold",)).grid(row=0,column=2,padx=20,pady=5)
    phone_entry = Entry(f1,bg="white", width=15, textvariable=phone_entered,font=("Candara",15),bd=5, relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=0,column=3,pady=5,padx=20)

    x = random.randint(100000,1000000)

    bill = Label(f1, text="Customer Bill ID",bg=colorbg,fg="white", font=("Candara",18,"bold",)).grid(row=0,column=4,padx=20,pady=5)
    bill_entry = Label(f1,bg="white",text=x,fg="#8d99ae", width=15, font=("Candara",15),bd=5, relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=0,column=5,pady=5,padx=20)
    billbtn = Button(f1, text="New Bill",width=10,bd=7,font="Candara 12 bold",command=yes).grid(row=0, column=6,padx= 10, pady=20)


#===============================================================Driving Code===========================================================    
LoginPage() #deleted for the time being (to submit this question)
```

I still am getting this error:

```
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: one() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

What is the thing I'm doing wrong?
I tried to search every site but I failed to find out the solution.

Comment: Please post the ***full*** error traceback along with a [mre] of your code

Answer (score 0):

The `missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` error is raised when you do not instantiate an `object` of a class before calling a `class method`.

To solve this error, make sure that you first `instantiate` an object of a class before you try to access any of that class' methods.

Comment: Did this work? If yes, please mark it with the green checkmark so that people with the same problem can find the answer quickly. :)